# Python GUI that contains a Countdown Timer and a String that were handed over during the runtime

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

I am currently trying to implement a GUI as kind of a 'Presentors' Toolkit'. 
It shall contain how much time you have left on your presentation and who shall be the next speaker. 
I manage to build the GUI with boxes, where I can insert the time and the name of the next speaker, but somewhat I can't manage to get my head around the display of name and time (updated every second).

The program will start, when I hit the start button, but also will not terminate.

I have tried a couple of things and also checked out other stack overflow entries but couldn't manage to transfer those approaches to mine.

My code looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import datetime


#build the GUI
window = Tk()
window.title("presenters Toolkit")

lbl_duration = Label(window, text = "duration [mins]")
lbl_duration.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

presentationDuration = Entry(window, width = 10)
presentationDuration.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

lbl_speaker = Label(window, text = "next Speaker")
lbl_speaker.grid(column = 2, row = 0)

nextSpeaker = Entry(window, width = 25)
nextSpeaker.grid(column = 3, row = 0)

lbl = Label(window, text = "", font = ("Arial Bold", 50))
lbl.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

left_Time = Label(window, text ="--", font = ("Arial Bold", 50))
left_Time.grid(column = 0, row = 4)

mid_Time = Label(window, text = ":", font = ("Arial Bold", 50))
mid_Time.grid(column = 1, row = 4)

right_Time = Label(window, text = "--", font = ("Arial Bold", 50))
right_Time.grid(column = 2, row = 4)

btn = Button(window, text = "start", command = clicked)
btn.grid(column = 1, row = 3)

#method, that will act upon clicking the 'start button'
def clicked():
    t = float(presentationDuration.get())
    nSpeaker = nextSpeaker.get()
    t = int(t*60)
    update(t, nSpeaker)

#method, that shall update the labels according to the time and that shall do this only once every second
def update(t, nSpeaker):
        h = int(t//3600)
        m = int(t//60)
        s = int(t-3600*h-60*m)
        while t >= 0:
            left_Time.configure(text = m)
            mid_Time.configure(text = ":")
            right_Time.configure(text = s)
            lbl.configure(text = nSpeaker, bg = "red", font = ("Arial Bold", 50))
            t = t - 1
            window.after(1000, update(t, nSpeaker))

window.mainloop()
```

I still have the calculations for the hour included, though I believe that won't be necessary since presentations usually don't go that long.

Thank you very much for any approach to help me!

All the best :)

Comment: First you should update speaker in `clicked()` instead of `update()` as the speaker will not be changed during `update()` being called.  Second you don't need the while loop in `update()` and you used `after()` in a wrong way.  Inside `update()`, just calculate `m` and `s` using `m, s = divmod(t, 60)`, update `left_Time` and `right_Time` and then call `window.after(1000, update, t-1)`.  Also you need to check whether `t >= 0` before doing the above steps in `update()`.

Comment: Hey,
Thank you very much! Your comments were applicable and the program now runs :)..
Also nice to know about the divmod function.. didn't know it before. Thanks for taking the time! Dearly appreciated :)